# Create a table while sending email from list SharePoint online. Attached is the image

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]

I want to create this table and be sent as an email when I click save in the Sharepoint List. Can anyone help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow and insert "Send an email" action into it. In the email action, click **Properties**, then you can set HTML format in **Body**.
[image]

For the workflow, please set it to automatically start when an item is created or changed.

There are some references for you:
[How to customize workflow email body?](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-customize-workflow-email-body/)
[How to Create HTML Email Message in SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-create-html-email-message-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/)

Answer (score 1):

IF you're not tied to the exact table format view above, and IF you're only interested in the table information that shows up in the above graphic, you could use a workflow that fires off an email each time a list item is created, and perhaps also when a record is revised, if that is your further wish (Changeable in the workflow settings).   The body of the email would consist of the table info and variables (visually sorted however you wish), the variable information for sender and recipient would also be dependent on what your needs are (I don't believe you mentioned them in particular).

Comment: I did create a workflow, however i need to get information only when a user enters any information to the list, I created a table in html body and all the list information is being populated. I am confused how to do it

Comment: You can form your html body dynamically by appending it if value is true and pass that body as the end.

Comment: By "...when a user enters any information into the list...", do you mean: 1: When a user creates a new item in the list, or 2:  When a user edits an existing item in the list?  If the answer is 1, you can set the workflow to run each time a new list item is created.  If the answer is 2, you can either run the workflow on edit OR set a condition in the workflow so that it runs each time certain fields are not blank.